# Failing to update from repository in MX linux

Tags: apt, upgrade, mx-linux

I use MX-Linux KDE version. Today, all on a sudden, when I tried to run `apt update`, the update process is not done fully. One of the resources man page showing a forbidden IP error. This is the result when I ran the code:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                          
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                                         
Hit:5 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                        
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                              
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                            
Hit:8 http://mxrepo.com/mx/repo buster InRelease                                                                             
Hit:9 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                         
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                
Ign:11 https://dl.bintray.com/openbangla/debian buster InRelease                                                         
Err:12 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.8.80.43 443]
Get:13 https://dl.bintray.com/openbangla/debian buster Release [1,840 B]
Err:15 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease 
  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.8.80.43 443]
Err:16 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb development InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.8.80.43 443]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.8.80.43 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/preview/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.8.80.43 443]
E: The repository 'https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/development/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.8.80.43 443]
E: The repository 'https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb development InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean` then, run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: The problem still persists.

Comment: There already is an issue about this in the TeamViewer Forum https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/113687/repository-is-no-longer-regarded-as-secure-no-update-possible-fehl-31-https-linux-teamviewer-com, I guess all we can do is wait

Comment: Chose another mirror with "MX Repo Manager" maybe it will work

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a temporary issue with Teamviewer reposiroties. I have found the following workaround:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list
```

Remove the broken source list file by the above command and try to get updates. To regenerate the above file, you'd need to update TW by downloading the deb package manually.

Answer (score 2):

It looks the issue is with the signature.

Probably better is to comment out the line in the repo file and to preserve it for a future update.

Just comment out the following line in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list

```
#deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
```